# How do I open a Flutter wep app page from an email link?

Tags: authentication, flutter-web

I currently have it so that when a root user adds a new user to group(via email), it will send a message to their inbox with a link to create a password on the web page. However, do not know how to create a link that will send them to a registration page on my Flutter web app after they click on it in their email. Any ideas?